# coalesce of a query in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query:

```
SELECT $ID_TABLE,
        TO_CHAR($DATE_COLUMN,'YYYYMMDD') ,
        '$UPPER_HOUR',
        COUNT(1)
FROM $TABLE_NAME
WHERE DATE_TRUNC('day',$DATE_COLUMN) = cast('$TODAY' as date)
        AND TO_CHAR($DATE_COLUMN,'HH24MI') BETWEEN '$LOWER_HOUR' AND '$UPPER_HOUR'
        GROUP BY TO_CHAR($DATE_COLUMN,'YYYYMMDD');
```

But in some cases the query has data in other cases is null.

Then if is null I need select other values, something like:

```
SELECT(coalesce(
SELECT $ID_TABLE,
        TO_CHAR($DATE_COLUMN,'YYYYMMDD') ,
        '$UPPER_HOUR',
        COUNT(1)
FROM $TABLE_NAME
WHERE DATE_TRUNC('day',$DATE_COLUMN) = cast('$TODAY' as date)
        AND TO_CHAR($DATE_COLUMN,'HH24MI') BETWEEN '$LOWER_HOUR' AND '$UPPER_HOUR'
        GROUP BY TO_CHAR($DATE_COLUMN,'YYYYMMDD')),select $ID_TABLE, $date, $PPER_HOUR, 0);"
```

Is possible do something like that.

This is for a process with a insertion with that select.

And if i don't have any row I need insert the values with constant date and the count(1)= 0.

The values with `$` are constants

Thanks ;)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help explain what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use `coalesce()` in this way only when the query returns a single value.

You can use a [plpgsql block](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html) and the [FOUND variable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS), like in this pseudocode:

```
do $$
begin
    insert into my_table
    <a select query>;

    if not found then
        insert into my_table
        values(<some default values>);
    end if;
end $$;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you mean:

```
WITH t as (
      SELECT $ID_TABLE as col1, TO_CHAR($DATE_COLUMN, 'YYYYMMDD') as col2,
             '$UPPER_HOUR' as col3,
             COUNT(1) as col4
      FROM $TABLE_NAME
      WHERE DATE_TRUNC('day',$DATE_COLUMN) = cast('$TODAY' as date) AND
            TO_CHAR($DATE_COLUMN, 'HH24MI') BETWEEN '$LOWER_HOUR' AND '$UPPER_HOUR'
      GROUP BY TO_CHAR($DATE_COLUMN, 'YYYYMMDD'
     )
SELECT *
FROM T
UNION ALL
SELECT v.*
FROM (VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)) v(col1, col2, col3, col4)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t);
```